# Ambassador Gateway : Grafana not redirecting properly in kubernetes environment

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, api-gateway, envoyproxy, ambassador

I have deployed Ambassador and grafana, then deployed Grafana service to expose via API gateway

```
[root@am26 granafa-service-21]# kubectl get svc
NAME                          TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)          AGE
ambassador                    NodePort    10.107.4.224     10.134.136.256   80:32555/TCP     6d17h
ambassador-admin              NodePort    10.106.171.141   <none>           8877:31193/TCP   6d17h
```

Here my Ambasador service

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: grafana2-ai-service
  annotations:
    getambassador.io/config: |
      ---
      apiVersion: ambassador/v1
      kind: Mapping
      name: grafana2-ai-mapping
      prefix: /grafana6/
      service: grafana2-ai-service
      rewrite: ""

spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 3000
      name: http
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: grafana
```

Trying to access UI with url http://10.134.136.256/grafana6/

Getting below message in UI, any idea how to fix this ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using Helm, you need to add this grafana.ini configuration:

```
## Using default values from https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/grafana/values.yaml
##
grafana:
  enabled: true
  namespaceOverride: ""
  # For mapping a path to ambassador
  grafana.ini:
    server:
      root_url: http://localhost:3000/grafana6/
      serve_from_sub_path: true
    paths:
      data: /var/lib/grafana/data
      logs: /var/log/grafana
      plugins: /var/lib/grafana/plugins
      provisioning: /etc/grafana/provisioning
    analytics:
      check_for_updates: true
    log:
      mode: console
    grafana_net:
      url: https://grafana.net
```

Or modify, directly, the grafana.ini file.